# No action button in create and edit of a many2many relationship odoo 11

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

There is no Save / Cancel button in the create and edit pop up of a many2many relation. 
Buttons appear only in debug mode.
Any idea ?[image]

Comment: Update your question with your model's xml code.

Answer (score 0):

check the rules and if in the xml the button's attribute invisible are true